# check_admin_referer fails on new AJAX plugin uninstall with "Are you sure you want to do this?"

Tags: ajax, uninstallation

Before WordPress core had AJAX plugin actions, uninstallation in `register_uninstall_hook()` worked fine:

```
 if ( ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) )
 return;

 check_admin_referer( 'bulk-plugins' );
```

It needs a real HTTP/POST, so if you you disable JavaScript in your browser on WP 4.9 it works.

But it fails with AJAX plugin uninstallation with *Are you sure you want to do this?*
I'd like to keep up strong security.

What is the solution? What is the AJAX counterpart of `check_admin_referer( 'bulk-plugins' )` in plugin uninstallation?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you already asked that on Slack, have you read the reply there?

Comment: Yes. I'll add the answer here too.

Comment: For a plugins there is no need to check user capabilities or nonces, core takes care about that.